# (Python) Trying to make a simple Counter (Book project)

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

Trying to make a simple counter in python
for a project in a "Learn Python Book"

Brief: Write a program that counts for the user.
       Let the user enter the starting number,
       the ending number and the amount by which
       to count.

What I have so far:

```
print ("Welcome to the program for those who are to lazy to count")
print ("You must be really really lazy too use this")

input ("\n Press any key to continue")

Num1 = input ("Please Enter Starting Number: \n")
Num2 = input ("Please Enter Ending Number: \n")
count = input ("Count up in: \n")

while (Num1 < Num2):
      Num1 += count
      print (Num1)
```

Not sure what is wrong with this code it get's stuck in an infinite loop could someone explain why? And possibly a fix :) 
it is stuck

Comment: Hint: `"100" < "9"` is True. `100 < 9` is False.

Comment: Mmm could you elaborate Num1 & Num2 Are variables so if I place them within "" quotation marks it will just treat them as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said, the `input()` function returns a type `string`, therefore you can't properly compare the values with the `<` operator.

You should first convert the type of `num1`, `num2` and `count` to integer with the Built-In function `int()` (see [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#int)).

Try this simplified version (no error handling):

```
Num1 = int(input ("Please Enter Starting Number: \n"))
Num2 = int(input ("Please Enter Ending Number: \n"))
count = int(input ("Count up in: \n"))
```

hope this help!

Comment: Thank you very much wish I had known about int ( )  such a small error ><

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing strings, as Kevin said. You would need to convert the inputs to int so that they can be properly compared with the < operator.

Comment: Ah ok i see is there a operator for that?

Comment: Your book doesn't mention the `int()` built-in function?

Comment: Not so far no when would i use int()

Comment: Is your book intended for Python 2?

Comment: Python 3 i think solved it with using the Int ( ) command thank you

Comment: If it's intended for Python 3 and doesn't even mention `int()` when telling you to compare integers, I don't think it's a very good book. You should try the [official Python tutorial](https:// docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) instead.